# Increment number in string C++

Tags: c++, string, int, increment

I'm trying to increment the name of the file based on the number associated with the filename. If I make the variable postFix an int type, it gives an error (understandably) since I can't concatenate an int to a string type.

In that case how do I increment string variable?

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) 
{
  std::string postFix = "1"; // int postFix = 1 gives an error
  std::cout << (std::string("Image" + postFix + std::string(".png")));
}
```

Comment: Please clarify "incrementing" a string variable.  What is the value of a string after it is incremented?  If I have the string "hello", what happens after it is incremented?

Comment: Another suggestion, you can make the filenames unique by adding a timestamp to the filename.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I want to increment the postFix value from 1 to 2 to 3 to.. 20 as for loop ends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) to create a `std::string` from your `int` value.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) 
{
    std::cout << "Image" + std::to_string(i+1) + ".png";
}
```

Although in this case you might as well just use the stream `operator<<`

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) 
{
    std::cout << "Image" << i+1 << ".png";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't; you use an integer variable, and make a string representation of it to build the file name: `std::to_string(n)`

Answer (score 1):

```
int value = atoi(postFix.c_str());
value++;
postFix = std::to_string(value);
```

Comment: Did you mean `int value = std::stoi(postFix);`? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol

Comment: Nope, i meant exactly what i put :), but yours works equally as well!

Answer (score 1):

use `std::to_string`

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) 
{
    int postFix = 1;
    std::cout << (std::string("Image" + std::to_string(postFix) + std::string(".png")));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Write simply

```
std::cout << std::string("Image" ) + std::to_string( i + 1 ) + ".png";
```

Or even like

```
std::cout << "Image" + std::to_string( i + 1 ) + ".png";
```

Or you can define at first a string

std:;string = "Image" + std::to_string( i + 1 ) + ".png";

and then output it

std::cout << s;

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're getting it more complicated than necessary.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
     std::cout << "Image" << i << ".png";
   }
```

or

```
for (int i = 1; i  <= 10; i++) {
    std::string filename = "Image" + std::to_string(i) + ".png";
    // do something with filename
}
```

`to_string(int)` appeared in C++11.

Answer (score 0):

Increment the `int` 'Number' as your wish, then convert it into string and finally append it with the file name (or exactly where you want).

Headers needed:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <locale>
#include <sstream>
#include <string> // this should be already included in <sstream>
```

And to convert the 'Number' to 'String' do the following:

```
int Number = 123;       // number to be converted to a string

string Result;          // string which will contain the result

ostringstream convert;   // stream used for the conversion

convert << Number;      // insert the textual representation of 'Number' in the characters in the stream

Result = convert.str(); // set 'Result' to the contents of the stream

          // 'Result' now is equal to "123"
```

This operation can be shorten into a single line:

```
int Number = 123;
string String = static_cast<ostringstream*>( &(ostringstream() << Number) )->str();
```

Reference taken from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/D9j2Nwbp/).

Comment: Erh - did you post your answer to the wrong question?

Comment: @kfsone, Im in the middle of editing